# Inverse of complex number imaginary part

Tags: complex-numbers

I have something like this
$$z+{\frac{1}{i}}$$
Which I expand:
$$z+{\frac{1}{i}} = x+yi+{\frac{1}{i}} = x+i(y+?)$$
I'm not sure what should be in place of $?$.

Assuming $i\times x = {\frac{1}{i}}$, then $x = {\frac{1}{i}} \div i = {\frac{1}{i}} \times {\frac{1}{i}} = -1$. But definitely, $i\times (-1) \neq {\frac{1}{i}}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$z+{\frac{1}{i}} = x+yi+{\frac{1\cdot i}{i\cdot i}} = x+yi+{\frac{i}{-1}}= x+iy-i=x+(y-1)i$$

and more in general for any $z\in \mathbb{C}\, z\neq 0$

$$\frac1{z}=\frac1{z}\frac{\bar z}{\bar z}=\frac{\bar z}{z \bar z}=\frac{\bar z}{\mid z \mid^2}$$

Comment: so, $${\frac{1}{i}}=-i$$? I just don't understand how? Well by expanding, yes. But, by intuition, no.

Comment: @user3132457 Yes exactly and indeed, to confirm the result, we ca check that $-i$ is the inverse of $i$ indeed $$-i\cdot i=-(-1)=1$$.